# Migrate from MySql to Sql server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, migration

I have Mysql dump file of around 200 GB, now I need to migrate into Sql server 2008. So What approach I should follow, should I go ahead with the line by line sql statement or is there any GUI tool available which suits to my requirement ?

Comment: BTW, 200MB is quite small. 200GB would be large (ish)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL v1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=69739c8c-ac82-41de-b9e6-8fa5ae2594d9&displaylang=en)

> Microsoft SQL Server Migration
>   Assistant (SSMA) is a toolkit that
>   dramatically cuts the effort, cost,
>   and risk of migrating from MySQL to
>   SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008, SQL
>   Server 2008 R2 and SQL Azure.

Comment: This is not working for me. Always showing some error while doing data migration

Comment: some error? Did you really expect help from that description?"