# Migrate big tables from MySql to MsSql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database-migration

I have a big database around 46GB in Mysql format and I managed to convert all the database to MSsql except two tables, the biggest ones. When I try to migrate those 2 tables, one by one , after a while I get the error message "The connection has been disabled"

I encreased the timeout from SSMA option from 15 to 1440 and decreased the bash from 1000 to 500 and same thing, The tables have 52 mil rows and 110 milion rows with 1,5 GB and 6.5 GB.

I tried incremential version but I don't have a unique id to use

What can I do to migrate them

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried to export the data into a file and then re-import it in the new database?

Comment: Didn't tried because of large tables rows, I think csv has limitation of how many rows can have

Comment: @GordonLinoff - would it be helpful to add an identity column at this stage ?

Comment: There is no limit on number of rows in a CSV file. There are limits (or resource limits) on  numbers of rows in some CSV tools. Should be easy to output all of your dat. a in the 2 big tables via a small client app if for some reason you can't use the native CSV export in MySql. https://ariejan.net/2008/11/27/export-csv-directly-from-mysql/ shows exporting directly to CSV from MySql. BCP the files in Sql server should not be a problem

Comment: If the size of the intermediate CSV file is an issue, can't you just transfer the dump through a _pipe_?

Comment: Not to throw you off your goal but why move to Sql server. MySQL is free, can be used with Entity Framework, has awesome Sharding features, I would only look towards Sql Server if you have a need for SSIS and SSRS

Comment: I had the same issue. Please see the answer in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266349/mysql-5-6-to-mssql-server-2014-migration-executereader-requires-an-open-and-av/38266748#38266748

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). You can create a dataflow that pulls from MYSql and dumps the Data into MSSQL.

You'll need to create a Data flow task that includes an OLE Database Source and connect it to an OLE Database Destination.

Comment: I already tried this software and without luck  , can you explain how to do this ?

Comment: Create a new "Integration Services Project" in Visual Studio.

Comment: Create a new "Integration Services Project" in Visual Studio. In the Control Flow tab, add "Data Flow Task" from the Toolbox on the left (or View>Toolbox). Double-click on the Data flow task. Now drag over ADO.NET Source and double-click it, create a New connection for your MySql server (Use MySQL Data provider) for the Provider. (MySQL data provider can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/03/04/connecting-to-mysql-from-ssis.aspx) Once the connection is made point the ADO.NET source at your Source DB and do the same for the SQL server (Using OLE DB instead of ADO.NET.

Comment: It actually looks like MySQL Provides an ADO.net driver: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using SSMA. I managed to migrate 100+ million rows of a table with 40+ columns.

I assume you've done the configuration well.
You need to ensure that there is no activity in the MSSQL database. No SELECTS over those tables and no any other activities.

Check out the two tables' structures to ensure they are fine. You can run the SSMA project only for those two tables.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed by using the following configuration described here in detail: [MySql 5.6 to MSSql server 2014 migration : ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266349/mysql-5-6-to-mssql-server-2014-migration-executereader-requires-an-open-and-av/38266748#38266748)

Also, I have documented the whole MySQL to MSSQL migration process here: [Migrate Data and Schema from MySQL to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475169/migrate-data-and-schema-from-mysql-to-sql-server/38299502#38299502)