# MySql 5.6 to MSSql server 2014 migration : ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration

**MySql:** 5.6
**MSSql:** 2014
**Tools Used:** SSMA for MySql

While migrating from mysql to mssql, all the structures for tables and views were migrated successfully. While migrating data, data was moved partially and I got the following errors.

```
ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.; SQL Server cannot access the source table <table-name>

The connection has been disabled.
```

There were other trivial issues as well like "**Column 'modified_on' does not allow DBNull.Value.**" which I have fixed manually by editing the table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Fix the `Column 'modified_on' does not allow DBNull.Value` issue, SQL Server management studio doesn't allow me to edit the structure. For that I had to change the configuration as follows.

> Open SQL Server management studio -> Goto Tools -> Options ->
>   Designers and uncheck "Prevent saving changes that require table
>   re-creation."

To Fix the following two issues:

```
ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.; SQL Server cannot access the source table <table-name>

The connection has been disabled.
```

**Solution:**

> Open SSMA for MySql -> Goto Tools -> Project Settings -> Select
>   General from the left menu -> Select Migration -> In the **Misc** section
>   -> set data migration timeout in minutes = 500
>
> Open SSMA for MySql -> Goto Tools -> Project Settings -> Select
>   General from the left menu -> Select Migration -> In the **Parallel data migration** section
>   -> set **Parallel data migration mode** from **Auto** to **Custom** and set Thread Count from **10** to **5**
>
> Run the data migration again.

I hope it helps.